# Why does 'A' = 0 in this piece?

Tags: c

I am reading through C for Dummies and am having trouble deciphering something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
#define OMEGA ('Z' - 'A')

int main() {
  int done;
  long int r; 
  char alpha; 

  srandom((unsigned)time(NULL)); 

  done = FALSE; 

  while(!done) {
    r = random() % OMEGA; // basically, OMEGA = 25 
    alpha = 'A' + (char)r;
    if (alpha =='Q') done = TRUE;
    putchar(alpha);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I understand that #define OMEGA ('Z' - 'A') is limiting the constant to 0 -  25. Please correct me if that is wrong.
What I have trouble with is alpha = 'A' + (char)r;
Why does 'A' not 65 (in regards to the ASCII?) Why is 'A' = 0? What part of the code is making 'A' = 0?

I altered the code so that variable 'r' would be printed out as well, and it confirmed that 'A' = 0

Comment: `'A'` is not 0, where are you getting that idea from?

Comment: "#define OMEGA ('Z' - 'A') is limiting the constant to 0 - 25." should be wrong. this line is just defining a constant with a value `('Z' - 'A')`, which is the character code for `Z` minus the character code for `A`. This won't typically be `0 - 25`.

Comment: @MikeCAT the result of `('Z' - 'A' )` is `(90-65)` = 25

Comment: The **Standard** C library routines are `srand` and `rand`; maybe you are using a compiler that adds the `random` and `srandom` defintions but, if so, you need to tell us that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `0 - 25` is `-25`, not `25`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The C Standard doesn't require the codes for Latin letters to be either contiguous or in order. Nor does it enforce use of the ASCII codes.

Comment: No part of the code makes 'A' equal to `0`. I think the insight you lack is that 'A' + 1 is equal to 'B'. This code is picking random letters between 'A' and 'Z'.

Comment: You need the (fixed) operand of your remainder operator to be **26**, not 25.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No! It's picking random letters between `A` and `Y` (inclusive), assuming an ASCII code base.

Comment: Is this code taken from the book or did you write it yourself?

Comment: @AdrianMole Until 'Q'. At least that appears to be the intention.

Comment: @Lundin it is in the book

Comment: @MikeCAT: OP’s “0 - 25” does not mean “0 minus 25.” It means “the interval from 0 to 25.”

Comment: @LeighAlford Ok if this is the verbatim then it would appear that you've gotten the wrong one, since this appears to be "C _by_ Dummies". Get rid of that book.

Comment: @AdrianMole srandom and random would be some *nix/POSIX flavoured ones I believe. For the sake of creating non-standard functions just for the heck of it... I don't think they are any different than the standard C equivalents.

Comment: The point of the program is to chose a random letter within the alphabet, and if the random letter is Q the program quits. 
0-25 should be read as '0 through 25', not '0 minus 25'
If you print 'r', you will see the pattern that when the number is '0', it will print 'A'. When the number is '2', it will print 'B', so on and so forth. 
My confusion is to why '0' would print 'A', if ASCII says that 'A' is 65

Comment: @LeighAlford 90-65 then `'A' + r` adds `0-24` (integer value) not `'0' - ...` (character symbols).

Comment: And well apparently this book is infamous and belongs on that anti-recommendation list we ought to make somewhere...

Comment: @Lundin I had no clue the book was problematic, thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @AdrianMole "*The C Standard doesn't require the codes for Latin letters to be either contiguous or in order. Nor does it enforce use of the ASCII codes*" - I'm aware of that. But I'm also aware that most common compilers do settle on ASCII, and people who write code like this are assuming/configuring the compiler to use ASCII. This kind of code doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is assuming that a character table is used where all letters are placed in a contiguous sequence from `'A'` to `'Z'`. This is actually not guaranteed by the C standard, but it is the most common scenario by far.

`#define OMEGA ('Z' - 'A')` is then indeed very likely the same as 90-65 = 25. The randomization `random() % OMEGA` (assuming it works like standard C `rand`) will give a value from 0 to 24.

Therefore `'A' + (char)r;` is the same as adding a value between 0 and 24 to `'A'`. The result is a value between `'A'` (65) and `'Y'` (89).

---

Notably:

- Surely this could should have given a value between `'A'` (65) and `'Z'` (90) instead. If the code was from a book, then the book is bad.
- The book should mention that letters `'A'` to `'Z'` aren't guaranteed to be sequential.
- `srandom` and `random` is non-standard. The standard C functions are `srand` and `rand`. If the book told you to use non-standard functions it should mention why.
- `(char)r` is completely pointless. There's a whole story regarding the types C use for character constants, but I won't go into this here. If the book told you to do this cast, the author is confused. Also there is no apparent reason why `r` should be declared as `long`.

If the book didn't leave notes about these things, then I would advise to find a better one.

Answer (score 6):

`'A'` is 65 on a ASCII-based system, not zero.

You printed `r` when you needed to print `alpha`.

When `r` is zero, `alpha` ends up being `'A'` (65), but that's because you add `'A'` (65) to it.

---

Note that this program fails on an EBCDIC-based machine since the letters are not continuous in EBCDIC characters sets. But `'A'` isn't zero there either.

Also note that the code won't ever generate a `Z`. Use `#define OMEGA ('Z' - 'A' + 1)` if that's unintentional.

Answer (score 3):

This code prints random letters, and it is based on the assumption that, in the machine's character set, the 26 capital letters `A` through `Z` have contiguous values.  In fact, that's a pretty reasonable assumption.  In [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which virtually all machines these days use, the codes for the letters `A` through `Z` are 65 to 90.

You seem to be imagining that the letter `A` should have the value 0.  But it absolutely does not, and this code does not assume that it does.

*If* the letter `A` had the character code 0, then you could just generate random numbers in the range 0–25 and use them as capital letters.  But since `A` does not have the character code 0, what you actually have to do is generate random numbers in the range 0–25 and then add some offset.  For ASCII, the appropriate offset is 65, because if you take `random() % 26` and add 65, you get random numbers in the range 65–90, corresponding to the letters `A`–`Z`.

And then by saying `alpha = 'A' + r` (rather than `alpha = 65 + r`), you make it more obvious what's going on, since no one has to wonder what that magic value `65` would have meant.  You also, theoretically, make your code more portable to some hypothetical other machine that doesn't use ASCII as its character set (and where, perhaps, `A` has some value other than 65).

(Now, in fact, there is no character set other than ASCII in widespread use, so this concern is pretty theoretical.  The one basic character set other than ASCII that was ever widespread was [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), where `A` had a value of 193, but where the letters were *not* contiguous, so this code wouldn't have worked anyway.)

By the way, the code has at least one other problem.  It doesn't print all 26 letters randomly, because its computation of OMEGA is in error, demonstrating the classic [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  So the code will only pick 25 letters, never choosing Z.